# Getting an "," error with lapply when trying to return count of labels

Tags: r

I'm trying to get this output, where stars, n.s., and missing are labels for different pvalues, which looks like:

```
      *      **     ***    ****      missing      n.s. 
     24      45      19      110       5          204
```

My dput(head(nav$pvalue)):

```
c(0.001772662, 0.917041262, 0.825266165, 0.163495324, 1.07e-08, 
1.44e-18)
```

I used:

```
pType<-function (p.1) {
    if(is.na(p.1)==TRUE){return()
}else if (0.05 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.01) {
print("*")
}else if (0.01 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.001) {
print("**")
}else if (0.001 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.0001) {
print("***")
}else {
print("*")
}
c.1a <- lapply((nav[,6], pType)
c.1a
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:12:24: unexpected ','
11: }
12: c.1a <- lapply((nav[,6],
                           ^
Traceback:
```

Comment: It is better to use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`.  Also, in the first expression, you are `return` ing NULL ` if(is.na(p.1)==TRUE){return()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use vectorized options such as `ifelse/case_when`.  Here, in the code, the first expression is returning NULL and all others are just `print`ing and not returning values.  We can use

```
pType<-function (p.1) {
    if(is.na(p.1)){NA
   }else if (0.05 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.01) {
    "*"
     }else if (0.01 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.001) {
    "**"
    }else if (0.001 >= p.1 & p.1 > 0.0001) {
   "***"
    }else {
    "*"
    }
}
sapply(v1, pType)
```

---

Or another option is `cut/findInterval`

```
cut(v1, breaks = c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05), labels = c("***", "**", "*"))
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(between(v1, 0.01, 0.05) ~ '*', 
          between(v1, 0.001, 0.01) ~ '**', 
          between(v1, 0.0001, 0.001) ~ "***", 
     TRUE ~ "*")
```

---

Or `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fcase(between(v1, 0.01, 0.05), '*', 
          between(v1, 0.001, 0.01),  '**', 
          between(v1, 0.0001, 0.001), "***",
           "*")
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, but how about using lapply? I want to utilize pType function with lapply to get the type of all values in the   -value column in nav. and then I want to save the summary counts of each type (as factors) to new object (let's say sumtype)

Comment: @user432797 just change the `sapply` in first solution to `lapply`

Comment: I tried both sapply and lapply, @akrun, and both return (list) all the values, not the output that I was looking for.